# How to write at the same time to Different excel Using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I try to write to all files, that I have at the same time.
I have some files

```
izzymonroe@mail.ru.xlsx, 
lucky-frog@mail.ru.xlsx, 
lucky-frog@mail.ru.xlsx, 
izzymonroe@mail.ru.xlsx,
Yubodrova@ya.ru.xlsx,
lucky-frog@mail.ru.xlsx,
Ant.karpoff2011@yandex.ru.xlsx
9rooney9@list.ru.xlsx
```

and I want to write data to this. But how can I send it to function(and I need to write to file value with **groupby**)

```
df = pd.read_excel('group.xlsx')
def add_xlsx_sheet(df, sheet_name=u'Смартфоны полно', index=True, digits=1,    path='9rooney9@list.ru.xlsx'):
    book = load_workbook(path)
    writer = ExcelWriter('9rooney9@list.ru.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    if sheet_name in list(writer.sheets.keys()):
        sh = book.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
        book.remove_sheet(sh)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=u'Смартфоны полно', startrow=0, startcol=0,
            float_format='%.{}f'.format(digits), index=index)
    writer.save()
```

It works to one file, but it write all data to this file. But I need to write group, where id in **mail** complies the name of file
How can I specify all file in function and next

```
df.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda g: g.to_excel(str(g.name) + '.xlsx', 'sheet2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with `df.groupby('col_name').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, x.name, path='{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))`